# how to cast json output field to date type

Tags: json, postgresql

I used a wrapper between mongodb and postgres.
Now, I got my tables and my data and I can access to it.

now, when I listed my table, I found that the field date that is under an object is not type date or timestamp,

let me explain more with short scree,

[image: this is my object from mongoldb, date is a type date]

When I use postgeSQL, my object is converted to json and I got all the fields, but no more dates. but numbers,like in the screen shot

[image: second]

and I can't alter the type of the field date. 
what should I do?

Comment: in second case it is unix timestamp. In first timestamp in JS format. Give us code if you want help - mongo and postgres seem to understand each other perfectly

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: CREATE FOREIGN TABLE rents( _id NAME,  "from" json, ) SERVER mongo_server OPTIONS (database 'tr', collection 'rents');
this is my table,
what do u need else?